# format specifier for double in scanf

Tags: c, double, scanf, format-specifiers

I wrote this program for getting a double input:

```
double n;
scanf("%lf",&n);
while(fgetc(stdin)!='\n')
    return 0;
printf("%lf",n);
```

This program is supposed to take double as input. Provided that `%lf` is the format specifier for `double` in **`scanf`**, I used it. But for inputs of a digit followed by e. ex.(3e), the input is being read without errors. But during processing of the same variable, it is discarding the `e` and only considering `3` as is shown by the `printf` statement. What is the cause of such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the rationale given in defect report #22 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/docs/rr/dr_022.html), functions like `scanf` (with `%lf`) and `strtod` should consume as much input as satisfies the expected format for the floating point constant. This means that they should consume the `e` character in `"3e"` even though the `e` character is not followed by the actual exponent value (the exponent value is required to be present by 6.4.4.2).

This applies in equal degree to `%lf` and `%f`. In my experiments they behave exactly the same on this input. (Of course, `%f` requires target variable of type `float`.)

However, even after consuming both `3` and `e` from the input stream, I would expect `scanf` (and `strtod`) to recognize `"3e"` as an invalid representation of a floating point number (since, again, 6.4.4.2 requires the exponent value to be present) and act accordingly. In my experiment `scanf` successfully read `3.0`. This I cannot explain yet.

Comment: @darknight: Not sure what you mean. I don't see any difference in the behavior for `%lf` and `%f`. The standard specifies `%lf` for `double` in `scanf`. `%f` is for `float`.